# Django queryset - sorting twice

Tags: python, django, sorting

How do I get a sorted queryset of Projects to display Departments alphabetically with Teams in each department also alphabetic?

Símple models are like this...

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Teams(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dept = models.ForeignKeyField(Department, on_delete=CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKeyField(Teams, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

In Views.py I want to collect the teams and display them by Department alphabetically with the number of projects for each Team.

```
...
team_list = []
teams_ = Teams.objects.all().order_by('dept__name')
for team in teams_:
    projects = Project.objects.all(team=team)
    team_list.append((team, len(projects)))
return render(request, 'index.html', {'team_list': team_list})
```

Then in the template...

```
<ul>
{% for team, len in team_list %}
<li><a href="{% url 'team_detail' team.id %}">{{ team.dept.name|upper }} - {{ team.name|capfirst }} ({{ len }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This displays something like this...

```
Archive - Backup (22)
Archive - Archive (3)
Support - Glossary (32)
Support - A Team (12)
Support - Members (22)
```

Which is not correct - I want an ordered alphabetic list with departments and teams like this...

```
Archive - Archive (3)
Archive - Backup (22)    
Support - A Team (12)
Support - Glossary (32)
Support - Members (22)
```

Comment: `('name', 'dept')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use **Teams.objects.all()**,just order_by will work equally fine: and then order by those fields with separate commas,like this :

```
team_list = []
teams_ = Teams.objects.order_by('dept','name')
for team in teams_:
    projects = Project.objects.all(team=team)
    team_list.append((team, len(projects)))
return render(request, 'index.html', {'team_list': team_list})
```

Comment: I would suggest a following edit: retrieving teams like `teams_ = Teams.objects.order_by('dept','name').annotate(team_count=Count('projects'))`, followed by `team_list = [(x, x.team_count) for x in teams_]`. That way you can get it in one query.